# Looking for a customizable "flowchart builder " builder

Tags: flowchart, gui-designer, dia

I need to create a customized graphical flowchart builder. There are only three classes of connectable components, and two kinds of connectors from which the flowchart is constructed. Each component and connector class, though, needs to have a tailored set of properties associated with the instances of their class.

So I'm looking for a "flowchart builder" builder that lets me configure the types of components, the associated properties, and has all the plumbing already in place to handle drag/drop, resizing, drawing, connecting, load/save, and so on.

Ideally the resulting application would save diagrams in an XML-based format, but anything parsable would be fine.

Dia has the capabilities I'm looking for, however, customizing it for a new type of diagram requires coding up the specifics of the component set. I'm looking for something that on a much shorter timeframe constructs a flowchart application ideally based on the content of component and connector configuration definitions.

Comment: I was going to say Visio, but based on your comparison choice, it sounds like you want something free that runs on Linux.

Comment: Free and Linux is preferred, but nothing is being ruled out. I haven't used Visio in many years, is it actually as configurable as I'm requesting?  Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Dia: It might not be necessary to "code" your components. Maybe you can simply "draw" them:

http://dia-installer.de/howto/create_shape/index.html.en

Such shapes can also be equipped with attributes (you'll have to do some XML-Editing for this):

http://git.gnome.org/browse/dia/tree/doc/custom-shapes#n260

I'm not sure if you were aware of this information.

Comment: When I looked into Dia I saw that there was some support for just drawing up a component set, but what I was looking for was extensive enough that I would've needed to code it.  And I've already got too many irons in the fire as it is :-) I still have the need for this, but the urgency is low. If/when it gets bumped up, well, either I or someone else on the team will get this as an assignment.